# Why does ElementTree reencode my string?

Tags: python, xml, encoding, elementtree

See:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

>>> xmlstring = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
... <dm>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
...     &lt;string&gt;R\xc3\xa9sum\xc3\xa9&lt;/string&gt;
... </dm>
... """
```

The XML source is UTF-8 encoded (`\xc3\xa9` = é):

```
>>> print xmlstring
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dm>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
     &lt;string&gt;Résumé&lt;/string&gt;
</dm>
```

Now, let's parse this:

```
>>> dm = et.fromstring(xmlstring)
>>> dm.text
u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n     <string>R\xe9sum\xe9</string>\n'
```

As you can see, the `\xc3\xa9` (utf-8) characters have been converted to `\xe9` (iso-8859-1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is normal Python behaviour; you are looking at a **unicode** string *representation*, one that can be pasted back into a Python interpreter without encoding problems as any non-ASCII or non-printable byte is represented as an escape code. Note that the *newlines* are also represented by their `\n` escape code.

Use `print dm.text` to write out the byte values without Python string literal representation:

```
>>> text = u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n     <string>R\xe9sum\xe9</string>\n'
>>> print text
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <string>Résumé</string>
```

The codepoints are *unicode* codepoints, but because they are below U+0100 Python represents them with the `\x..` escape code. Higher codepoints would use the `\u....` escape code. In the Unicode standard, code points below U+0100 match the Latin 1 standard.

If you expected UTF-8 bytes instead, then encode the Unicode value to UTF-8 again:

```
>>> text.encode('utf8')
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n     <string>R\xc3\xa9sum\xc3\xa9</string>\n'
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're using Python < 3 did you try : # -*- coding: utf8 -*-
else Python will use an encoding depending of implementation.

Comment: Specifying the codec in the source file **only** applies to how Python reads string literals in the source code. Since the source code in the OP sample only uses escape codes for non-ASCII codepoints, setting the codec to UTF8 **makes no difference** since all that the source is using is ASCII. How unicode values from other sources are treated is not changed by setting the source code codec.